# py2exe trouble for multiple scripts

Tags: python, py2exe

I am working on a project on python. I have divided my complete script into 4 modules to make the code better understandable. I need to create a exe of the code which holds the gui.

The problem is that different modules have different dependencies.One module requires pyusb, one requires PIL and other requires scipy. How do i make sure that making an exe of one code itself is sufficient to handle all the dependencies. I dont mind making a single exe from multiple codes. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify list of packages to include (along with subpackages) as value to the key *package* 
and list of module names to include as value to the key *includes* in the *options* dictionary that can be passed to py2exe. Check this [py2exe help](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) page for list of options that one can use to configure py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

By default py2exe should include all your imports into the bundle, but if this doesn't work, you can try false-importing the modules you need. you can do this in the main script that you are passing to py2exe:

in your main script:

```
if False:
    import <module x>, <module y>, <module z>, <etc...>
```

This should make py2exe see the modules right away, and include them with your bundle.